# Rails4 when update one column how to get this update time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I used `Rails4.2.8` and the database is `Mysql` .

My database tables has many `columns`: 
 `name`, `phone`, `email`, `address` and so on.

When user change `name`, and record the change happened time, then tell user "You Can Change Your Name After 30 Days".

How could I get the user change happened time?

Such as this picture:

[image: The example]

My database already has `created_at` and `updated_at`, but I found that when I update user informations(not only `name`) ,the `updated_at` will change ,but now I want when the user change `name` , I could get the time record when change happened.This is some of my database:

[image: some of database]

++++++++++++****************************************+++++++++++++++

I had try with @DickieBOy and change some of the codes, but when I update user informations , I get the `No route matches [POST]`  error? Where did I have the wrong? Please help me .

Some codes of my `user.rb`:

```
validate :name_change
  def name_change
    if name_changed?
      self.name_updated_at = Time.now
    end
  end

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed?
  end
```

Some codes of my `user_helper.rb`:

```
def edit_day
    edit_days = (@user.name_updated_at + 30.days).to_i
    ctime = Time.now.to_i
    st = (edit_days - ctime) / 1.day
    if st > 0
      return st
    else
      return 0
    end
  end
```

And some codes of my `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <div class="user_profile-infoEdit">
      <%= f.label :name, "name", class: "userLabel " %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "userNameEdit" %>
      <br>
      <span class="text-gray fs12">30days can change one time
        <span>Have
          <span id="editDays"><%= edit_day %></span>  
          days can you change your name
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I found that with `def edit_day` , when I update user , It will always get `the No route matches [POST] "/users/udaskffa"` wrong? What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: You'd need a datetime column tracking when a user changes their name that would get updated from the model via a method that does what you want upon update.

Comment: How could I add the `datetime` column to user table , and how I can associate the `datetime` with column `name` , Could you give me the codes , @bkunzi01,thanks so much . I'm a novice for Rails , I had google many times , but I also don't how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @SylorHuang check the answer given below , it can be helpful for you, and let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @SylorHuang Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you, inacse you need any help you can ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding in a field called `name_updated_at`. With a default of the date it is created.

Rails has a feature where you can check if something changed.

`name_of_field_changed?`

In this case:

```
name_changed?
```

I would recommend checking this in the validation.

```
validate :name_change_is_outside_of_day_limit, if: name_changed?

def name_change_is_outside_of_day_limit
  if name_updated_at && name_updated_at < Date.today - 30.days
    errors.add(:name, "can't be changed within 30 days of the last change.")
  end
end
```

This is untested but it should work.

When you call `save` on the record it will fail the validation. The message can then be returned to the user.

This differs from the accepted answer by doing it at model level. This is where validation should be contained.

Comment: Hi,@DickieBoy , I think with your codes is the best way to solve this problem, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi,@DickieBoy, I had a new wrong with the codes, and I had edit the questions again , could you help me ? Thanks so much..

Comment: @SylorHuang if you haven't solved this, i would recommend asking a different question.

Comment: Thanks @ DickieBoy ,I had solved this problem. Thanks for your concern。

Answer (score 2):

Using migration add a column in users `name_updated_at:datetime`
 At the time when user is created with name then set this filed with current time-

```
def create
  @user =  User.create(user_params)
  if @user.name.present?
   @user.update(name_updated_at: Time.now)
  end
end
```

and on update action  do something like ~

```
def update
  @user = User.find(Parma[:id])
  if @user.name_updated_at <= Time.now - 30.days
     #allow user to update name
     @user.update(name: params[:name], name_updated_at:  Time.now)
  else
     #send back user with error
     flash[:error] = "you can change name after 30 days from last updated time"
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: if @user.name_updated_at <= Time.now - 30.days

Comment: OK ，@Gabbar, Thanks for your help . Because I'm outside  today , so I hadn't check your answer right now . But  I had read your codes, I think it will be helped for me . Thanks again , I will feedback the result tonight.

Comment: Hi,@Gabbar,maybe your codes is also a good method , But sorry that I think @DickieBoy is the appropriate method for me ,thanks for your help any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column 'updated_at' of date-time type to your table. We usually use timestamps for this which make a column for created_at and updated_at in the table.
Suppose you want to add timestamps to an existing users table:-

```
class AddTimestampsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_timestamps(:users)
  end
end
```

Furthermore, if you ever create a new table add timestamps to it.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migration-overview

Comment: Hi @AHK, thanks for your help , I had change my questions . In fact , that I had `created_at` and `updated_at` in my tables. Now what I want is that when the user change name , I could get the time record when change happened.

Comment: Gabbar has posted the correct answer. Try that code. It will work!